# How to download a SSL certificate from Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, file-transfer

I am currently trying to setup a SSL certificate for my website. I used certbot and the certificate got successfully saved to: `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem`.

I am also using Cloudflare and now my question is, how can I access that certificate to be uploaded to Cloudflare?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It should be in the directory on the server

Comment: I don't know how I can have access to /etc/letsencrypt other than using ssh. Using FTP I cant see those folders

Comment: You can download the file using `scp` from a *nix machine, or `pscp` from putty's download page on a Windows machine.